# How to create a GRPC-compliant OkHttpClient?

Tags: ssl, grpc, okhttp, http2

I am trying to write a GRPC client using OkHttp. GRPC is (in very simplified terms) an http2 connection, with special headers. I can see that there have already been features added ([#4951](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4951), [#4267](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4267)) to make OkHttp compatible with GRPC.

Could someone provide an example / link of how to build a GRPC-compatible `OkHttpClient` session? Is this this even supported at present (Oct '19)?

I'm specifically particularly in how one goes about starting in `h2c` i.e. cleartext mode, as GRPC does not support the HTTP 1.x -> 2 upgrade protocol, [as per discussion on gitter](https://gitter.im/grpc/grpc?at=5d978f73874aeb2d23eaecd1), and my server doesn't support TLS.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [complete implementation](https://github.com/square/wire/blob/972df6b3f1e308e38cbfbd6ee0b8d2377aedabdc/wire-library/wire-grpc-client/src/jvmMain/kotlin/com/squareup/wire/internal/RealGrpcCall.kt).

Comment: 404 these days, anyone have another link?

Comment: @Adam Fixed the link!